# Multiprocessing from joblib doesn't parallelize?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, python-3.6, joblib

Since I moved from python3.5 to 3.6 the Parallel computation using joblib is not reducing the computation time.
Here are the librairies installed versions:
 - python: 3.6.3
 - joblib: 0.11
 - numpy: 1.14.0

Based on a very well known example, I give below a sample code to reproduce the problem:

```
import time
import numpy as np
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

def square_int(i):
    return i * i

ndata = 1000000 
ti = time.time()
results = []    
for i in range(ndata):
    results.append(square_int(i))

duration = np.round(time.time() - ti,4)
print(f"standard computation: {duration} s" )

for njobs in [1,2,3,4] :
    ti = time.time()  
    results = []
    results = Parallel(n_jobs=njobs, backend="multiprocessing")\
        (delayed(square_int)(i) for i in range(ndata))
    duration = np.round(time.time() - ti,4)
    print(f"{njobs} jobs computation: {duration} s" )
```

I got the following ouput:

- standard computation: 0.2672 s
- 1 jobs computation: 352.3113 s
- 2 jobs computation: 6.9662 s
- 3 jobs computation: 7.2556 s
- 4 jobs computation: 7.097 s

While I am increasing by a factor of 10 the number of ndata  and removing the 1 core computation, I get those results:

- standard computation: 2.4739 s
- 2 jobs computation: 77.8861 s
- 3 jobs computation: 79.9909 s
- 4 jobs computation: 83.1523 s

Does anyone have an idea in which direction I should investigate ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the primary reason is that your overhead from parallel beats the benefits. In another word, your `square_int` is too simple to earn any performance improvement via parallel. The `square_int` is so simple that passing input and output between processes may take more time than executing the function `square_int`.

I modified your code by creating a `square_int_batch` function. It reduced the computation time a lot, though it is still more than the serial implementation.

```
import time
import numpy as np
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

def square_int(i):
    return i * i

def square_int_batch(a,b):
    results=[]
    for i in range(a,b):
        results.append(square_int(i))
    return results

ndata = 1000000 
ti = time.time()
results = []    
for i in range(ndata):
    results.append(square_int(i))

# results = [square_int(i) for i in range(ndata)]

duration = np.round(time.time() - ti,4)
print(f"standard computation: {duration} s" )

batch_num = 3
batch_size=int(ndata/batch_num)

for njobs in [2,3,4] :
    ti = time.time()  
    results = []
    a = list(range(ndata))
#     results = Parallel(n_jobs=njobs, )(delayed(square_int)(i) for i in range(ndata))
#     results = Parallel(n_jobs=njobs, backend="multiprocessing")(delayed(
    results = Parallel(n_jobs=njobs)(delayed(
        square_int_batch)(i*batch_size,(i+1)*batch_size) for i in range(batch_num))
    duration = np.round(time.time() - ti,4)
    print(f"{njobs} jobs computation: {duration} s" )
```

And the computation timings are

```
standard computation: 0.3184 s
2 jobs computation: 0.5079 s
3 jobs computation: 0.6466 s
4 jobs computation: 0.4836 s
```

---

A few other suggestions that will help reduce the time.

1. Use list comprehension `results = [square_int(i) for i in range(ndata)]` to replace for loop in your specific case, it is faster. I tested.
2. Set `batch_num` to a reasonable size. The larger this value is, the more overhead. It started to get significantly slower when `batch_num` exceed 1000 in my case.
3. I used the default backend `loky` instead of `multiprocessing`. It is slightly faster, at least in my case.

From a few other SO questions, I read that the multiprocessing is good for *cpu-heavy* tasks, for which I don't have an official definition. You can explore that yourself.

Comment: Hi, I came to the same idea that the function square_int is too simple.
Thanks a lot for the last suggestions I will have a try.